# Convert CSS3 Html to Image

Tags: c#, css

How could you do a HTML to Image conversion that supports CSS3 using C#

I am trying to convert this HTML page with CSS3 effects to an image using C#

Sample Page:
http://www.firsthomebuyers.co/FeaturedImage/FeaturedImage.html

[image: Original HTML Page]

I have tried a couple of C# libraries and the following code to convert HTML to .PNG but they do not support CSS3 and so the image ends up looking like this?

[image: After HTML to Image]

Tried with this Library:
https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/

Also Tried with this Code:

```
        private static void StartBrowser()
    {
        _.P("Start Browser");
        _.P("Navigate to: {0}", CurrentConfig.Url);
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var browser = new WebBrowser
            {
                ScrollBarsEnabled = false,
                Width = CurrentConfig.Width,
                Height = CurrentConfig.Height
            };

            browser.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompleted;
            browser.Navigate(@"http://www.firsthomebuyers.co/FeaturedImage/FeaturedImage.html");

            //webBrowser.DocumentText = html;
            Application.Run();
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    static void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _.P("Render to: {0}", CurrentConfig.OutputFile);

        var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;

        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height))
        {
            browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, browser.Width, browser.Height));

            bitmap.Save("D:/Temp/ImgUtilTest/Test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        Application.ExitThread();
    }
```

Comment: Could do a screen shot

Comment: Thanks Andrew, using Screencapture is how I ended going. I found the styling issues were more an issue with the WebBrowswer control using IE 11 and when I used other tools many of which just did not work, they were using a version of WebKit that looked different to my example about which is in Chrome.  As this code was only for a personal use tool, I opted for the Start Chrome, Display HTML, Screen Capture Approach

Comment: Glad my funny comment helped!